# How to sanitize the user input and use in ddl and dcl command to avoid SQL injection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, checkmarx

I have a package which is used to create new user, new password for new users and alter password for existing user and give grant user role for users.

The function in the package takes input from the user and checks against a user table. If existing user it change the password, if new user creates new user.

The function is as follows: the `fp_userid` is directly concatenated in the `dbms_sql.parse` statement in all the procedures. I tried with execute immediate, but still i have to concatenate the values. I guess we can't bind values.

Can we bind the value for ddl, dcl statements? Or can we sanitize the user input to avoid SQL injection? How can I use `dbms_assert` package in this case?

```
Function fn_userexists(fp_userid IN varchar2)
return boolean
is
   cursor c is 
     select userid, password,userrole,deleted from user_db where userid = fp_userid

r_user c%rowtype;
begin
open c;
fetch c into r_user;
if c%notfound then
return false;
else if r_user.deleted = 'Y' then
if fn_oracleuserexists (fp_user) then
pr_dropuser (fp_user);
end if;
close c;
delete user_db where userid = fb_userid;
return false;
elsif not fn_oracleuserexists (fp_user) then
pr_createuser(fp_userid, fn_hid(r_user.password,fp_userid));
pr_grantuserrole(fp_userid, 'SMC_USER');
pr_grantuserrole(fp_userid, r_user.userrole);
return true;
end if;
return true;
end if;
return true;
end if;
exception 
when other then
return false;
end;
```

I tried with execute immediate statement but still the value is concatenate as below and shows SQL injection vulnerability in checkmarks scan as the value is concatenated.

```
execute immediate 'CREATE USER "'||pp_userid||'" IDENTIFIED BY "' || pp_password'"
                               DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP';
```

Comment: this is repeat post

Comment: Hi Paul W, i am sorry, it is not intented, i am not sure of how to ask question on top of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted can't compile, it is invalid because of

- misspelled parameter name (f**b**_userid, fp_user)
- missing terminating semi-colon in cursor declaration
- superfluous `end if` (that would be easier to spot if you properly formatted code)

Anyway: next time, consider posting something that at least looks OK at first sight. As of other issues, try to use a **single** `return` from a function, at the end of code. Also, the way you handle exceptions is most probably wrong. If anything happens, function returns `false` but you don't know whether it is because cursor returned *nothing* or because of an error. Until you figure it out and decide how to properly handle exceptions (log them? Send yourself an e-mail? Return different datatype? Something else), you'd rather let Oracle raise an error.

Here's your code, fixed - see if it helps.

```
Function fn_userexists(fp_userid IN varchar2)
  return boolean
is
  l_userid varchar2(100) := dbms_assert.enquote_name(fp_userid);

  cursor c is 
     select userid, password,userrole,deleted 
       from user_db 
       where userid = l_userid;
  r_user c%rowtype;
  result number;
begin
  open c;
  fetch c into r_user;
  if c%notfound then
     result := 0;
  else 
    if r_user.deleted = 'Y' then
       if fn_oracleuserexists (l_userid) then
          pr_dropuser (l_userid);
       end if;
       delete user_db where userid = l_userid;
       result := 0;

    elsif not fn_oracleuserexists (l_userid) then
       pr_createuser(l_userid, fn_hid(r_user.password,l_userid));
       pr_grantuserrole(l_userid, 'SMC_USER');
       pr_grantuserrole(l_userid, r_user.userrole);
       result := 1;
    end if;
  end if;

  close c;
  return result = 1;
end;
```

Comment: Littlefoot, thanks for your response, enquote_name is just enclose the string double quotes right,  how it will help to sanitize the user input